# Detect if a key code corresponds to a key that would input something in a field

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to determine if a key that is pressed is a key that would actually add something to an input? I.e., change it's value?

For example, if I had an input and I pressed the 'a' key, a letter will appear in the input, however, if I press the down key, the value of the input won't change.

Also, I've tried using a value changed listener but that only fires when I change press a key and then click out of the input, which isn't what I want. I need to use the keydown or keyup listeners and I need to know if the key that was pressed was a key that will actually change the value of the input.

Comment: You could either check the value of the input on every key press and check if it has changed (for example save it in local/session storage).
Otherwise, you would need to get the key code for every "useless" key for that particular input and ignore them for your operations.

Comment: Well I think `onKeyPress` fires when *any* button is pressed, and that event should also have the new value in it when that happens. So all you'd have to do is when a key is pressed, compared the new value to old one. If it's changed, the key was one which changes the input's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using a value changed listener but that only fires when I
>   change press a key and then click out of the input, which isn't what I
>   want.

Would an event that fires when the field value changes (at the time the key is pressed) help you?

JQuery:

```js
$('#someInput').on('input', function() { 
    $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
});
```

Vanilla JS:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#someInput');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    input.value // get the current value of the input field.
});
```